# How to visualize a state transition diagram in JUNG(Java Universal Network/Graph Framework)?

Tags: java, graph, jung, markov-chains

I  am stuck with the visualization part, I have created a DirectedSparseMultiGraph for the purpose of visualizing the following transition diagram. I want to draw it in the same manner as depicted in the [image.](http://s4.postimg.org/6ng7q4iel/dice_pic.gif) At the moment I am getting [this.](http://s24.postimg.org/hoefnru2d/testing.png)

I know that the problem lies with the layout, but I am new to the JUNG framework I am not able to get it right.

Here is the my code snippet:

*MyVertex* and *MyEdge* classes are simple classes with a field for their ID and the associated probability of the edge.

```
package testing.jung.in.eclipse;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.CircleLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.Layout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DirectedSparseMultigraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util.EdgeType;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.BasicVisualizationServer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.decorators.ToStringLabeller;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.renderers.Renderer.VertexLabel.Position;

public class BasicGraphCreation
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Graph<MyVertex, MyEdge> g = new DirectedSparseMultigraph<MyVertex, MyEdge>();
    MyVertex n0 = new MyVertex(0);
    MyVertex n1 = new MyVertex(1);
    MyVertex n2 = new MyVertex(2);
    MyVertex n3 = new MyVertex(3);
    MyVertex n4 = new MyVertex(4);
    MyVertex n5 = new MyVertex(5);
    MyVertex n6 = new MyVertex(6);
    MyVertex o1 = new MyVertex(001);
    MyVertex o2 = new MyVertex(010);
    MyVertex o3 = new MyVertex(011);
    MyVertex o4 = new MyVertex(100);
    MyVertex o5 = new MyVertex(101);
    MyVertex o6 = new MyVertex(110);

    g.addEdge(new MyEdge(0.5), n0, n1, EdgeType.DIRECTED);
    g.addEdge(new MyEdge(0.5), n1, n3, EdgeType.DIRECTED);
    g.addEdge(new MyEdge(0.5), n3, n1, EdgeType.DIRECTED);
    g.addEdge(new MyEdge(0.5), n1, n4, EdgeType.DIRECTED);
    g.addEdge(new MyEdge(0.5), n3, o1);
    g.addEdge(new MyEdge(0.5), n4, o2);
    g.addEdge(new MyEdge(0.5), n4, o3);
    g.addEdge(new MyEdge(0.5), n0, n2);
    g.addEdge(new MyEdge(0.5), n2, n5);
    g.addEdge(new MyEdge(0.5), n2, n6);
    g.addEdge(new MyEdge(0.5), n6, n2);
    g.addEdge(new MyEdge(0.5), n5, o4);
    g.addEdge(new MyEdge(0.5), n5, o5);
    g.addEdge(new MyEdge(0.5), n6, o6);

    Layout<MyVertex, MyEdge> layout = new CircleLayout<MyVertex, MyEdge>(g);
    layout.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600)); // sets the initial size of the space
    // The BasicVisualizationServer<V,E> is parameterised by the edge types

    BasicVisualizationServer<MyVertex, MyEdge> vv = new BasicVisualizationServer<MyVertex, MyEdge>(layout);
    vv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650, 650)); //Sets the viewing area size

    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller<MyVertex>());
    vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller<MyEdge>());
    vv.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Position.CNTR);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Directed Graph ");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(vv);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know where you want the vertices to be, use StaticLayout.

If you want a layout algorithm that will figure out how to create such a layout automatically, you will need to supply that yourself... and it's not going to be trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joshua, the example shown above is just for reference but what I am having is the vertex, edge and label information which may change as well and then I have to create a state machine like the one stated above, so StaticLayout will not do the job, Is creating an algorithm by myself only the valid option.
Can you suggest me some other open-source option for the visualization of Finite State Machines in java, I want to use it in another project, I have found http://jautomata.sourceforge.net/ but its development is stagnant since 2006.

Comment: Have you also came across this problem while creating JUNG2 layouts?

Comment: In cases where your graph is a tree or basically tree-like (as in your example), you can use TreeLayout.  There may be some decent existing algorithms for rendering FSMs--it's not something I've looked into--and if there are, you can implement them in JUNG without having to develop your own algorithm.  For what it's worth, the JUNG layout algorithms try to optimize for general graphs rather than trying to look like something specific; they emphasize force-directed layouts.  CircleLayout is very rarely the right answer.  Try checking out the ShowLayouts demo to play with different options.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Joshua, you are right about the graph being tree like but the problem here is that the kind of graphs I want to visualize will have parallel as well as self edges and TreeLayout does not support this kind of structure. Could it be possible that I can change the TreeLayout to support parallel edges and self loops. You guidance on how to proceed doing that would be of great help.

Comment: If you want the vertices to be laid out in a tree-like manner, with additional edges 'tacked on', then you might check out MinimiumSpanningTreeDemo.  Basically that takes a tree-shaped subgraph, calculates vertex positions for it, and then builds a StaticLayout using those vertex positions.